# How to remove undefined and null values from an object using lodash?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have a Javascript object like:

```
var my_object = { a:undefined, b:2, c:4, d:undefined };
```

How to remove all the undefined properties? False attributes should stay.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

If you want to remove all *[falsey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839953/16940)* values then the most compact way is:

For **Lodash 4.x and later**:

```
_.pickBy({ a: null, b: 1, c: undefined }, _.identity);
>> Object {b: 1}
```

For *legacy* Lodash 3.x:

```
_.pick(obj, _.identity);

_.pick({ a: null, b: 1, c: undefined }, _.identity);
>> Object {b: 1}
```

Comment: Please note that in lodash 4 this should be `_.pickBy(obj, _.identity);`

Comment: Plaese note this method will also remove false value.

Comment: @karthikvishnukumar: `_.pickBy(obj, x => x === false);`

Comment: Besides removing false, it will also remove atributes with 0 and '' as value... not a good idea.

Comment: This answer is not correc since it also removes falsy values. Check my answer below.

Comment: If the object is deep, how to do ?

Comment: Why is this an answer? It does not answer the question, it also deletes `0` and `false` values.

Comment: If you don't want to remove `false` values, here's an example:
```javascript
_.pickBy(obj, x => x === false || x)

```

Answer (score 339):

You can simply chain `_.omit()` with `_.isUndefined` and `_.isNull` compositions, and get the result with lazy evaluation.

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/7WFJzm2NKqENgcRKSt4C?p=preview)**

```
var result = _(my_object).omit(_.isUndefined).omit(_.isNull).value();
```

**Update March 14, 2016**:

As mentioned by [**dylants**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812765/how-to-remove-undefined-and-null-values-from-an-object-using-lodash/31209300#comment-57670185) in the comment section, you should use the [**`_.omitBy()`**](https://lodash.com/docs#omitBy) function since it uses a predicate instead of a property. You should use this for lodash version `4.0.0` and above.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ec35WjOFwD6YuO54tVEp?p=preview)**

```
var result = _(my_object).omitBy(_.isUndefined).omitBy(_.isNull).value();
```

**Update June 1, 2016**:

As commented by [**Max Truxa**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812765/how-to-remove-undefined-and-null-values-from-an-object-using-lodash/31209300?noredirect=1#comment62614789_31209300), lodash already provided an alternative [`_.isNil`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isNil), which checks for both `null` and `undefined`:

```
var result = _.omitBy(my_object, _.isNil);
```

Comment: Those that are using more recent versions of lodash should use the `omitBy` function instead of `omit`.  So `_(my_object).omitBy(_.isUndefined).omitBy(_.isNull).value();`

Comment: Since lodash 4.0.0 you can use [`_.isNil`](https://lodash.com/docs#isNil) instead of chaining `_.isUndefined` and `_.isNull`. This makes it even shorter: `var result = _.omitBy(my_object, _.isNil);`

Comment: @MaxTruxa how would u modify it to check for "Nil" values recursively?

Comment: You'd need an `omitBy` wrapper that supports deep omitting. See the first part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37250225/1825094).

Comment: Lodash's `omitBy` is less performant than `pickBy`, so the latter should be preferred, and the condition in the iteratee function reversed. The accepted answer above got that right.

Comment: The OP's question only specified `null` and `undefined` values. The `identity` predicate will also remove `false` values, so if you simply based it upon the question's intent then I don't see a problem with my answer. Additionally, if we're takling about "performance", `omitBy` simply calls `pickBy` with a negated `identity` predicate, by default. So, in terms of performance, it's too small to be significant.

Comment: May be trivial to some of you but important to mention for the rest: this is NOT recursive! If you want to omit nil values in nested objects you'll have to implement a recursive call!

Comment: HACK: If you only need to remove `undefined` and are working with simple objects: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`.

Answer (score 61):

The correct answer is:

```
_.omitBy({ a: null, b: 1, c: undefined, d: false }, _.isNil)
```

That results in:

```
{b: 1, d: false}
```

The alternative given here by other people:

```
_.pickBy({ a: null, b: 1, c: undefined, d: false }, _.identity);
```

Will remove also `false` values which is not desired here.

Comment: `{"a":1,"b":{"a":1,"b":null,"c":undefined}}` , object.b property `b`, 'c' will be not removed

Comment: @mqliutie as expected.

Answer (score 45):

if you are using lodash, you can use `_.compact(array)` to remove all falsely values from an array.

```
_.compact([0, 1, false, 2, '', 3]);
// => [1, 2, 3]
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#compact

Comment: compact applies to arrays but the question is about objects

Comment: Except I want to keep 0. Argh, so close.

Comment: @Sammi, you can use `_.pickBy(object, _.isNumber)` in that case.

Comment: @Herick No it's not. The question is about `undefined` and `null`, not 0 and false.

Comment: Hope this lets you sleep at peace @technophyle. Rephrasing:
This is now the best answer for whoever reached this question looking for falsy values removal.

Comment: Thank you @Herick. That works. I will go to sleep now.

Comment: Happy to help 

Comment: On second thought, I decided to downvote the answer since the question is about an object, not an array.

Comment: @technophyle, I agree with you (and I'm the one who wrote this answer, ha). But I'm keeping this answer up here because it, at the very least, solves *some* peoples problems.

Answer (score 26):

Just:

```
_.omit(my_object, _.isUndefined)
```

The above doesn't take in account `null` values, as they are missing from the original example and mentioned only in the subject, but I leave it as it is elegant and might have its uses.

Here is the complete example, less concise, but more complete.

```
var obj = { a: undefined, b: 2, c: 4, d: undefined, e: null, f: false, g: '', h: 0 };
console.log(_.omit(obj, function(v) { return _.isUndefined(v) || _.isNull(v); }));
```

Comment: Note that this is for Lodash v.3. For v.4, you have to use `_.omitBy`.

Answer (score 23):

To complete the other answers, in lodash 4 to ignore only undefined and null (And not properties like `false`) you can use a predicate in `_.pickBy`:

`_.pickBy(obj, v !== null && v !== undefined)`

Example below :

```js
const obj = { a: undefined, b: 123, c: true, d: false, e: null};

const filteredObject = _.pickBy(obj, v => v !== null && v !== undefined);

console.log = (obj) => document.write(JSON.stringify(filteredObject, null, 2));
console.log(filteredObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the best solution if you don't want to remove `0`, `''`, `false` values. Also you can shorten the callback to `v => v != null`.

Comment: Simple solution. Thank you for this.

Comment: This is very good and flexible solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

According to lodash docs:

```
_.compact(_.map(array, fn))
```

Also you can filter out all nulls

Answer (score 8):

with pure JavaScript: (although Object.entries is ES7, Object.assign is ES6; but equivalent ES5 uses Object.keys only should be also doable); also notice `v != null` checks for both null and undefined;

```
> var d = { a:undefined, b:2, c:0, d:undefined, e: null, f: 0.3, s: "", t: false };
undefined
> Object.entries(d)
    .filter(([ k, v ]) => (v != null))
    .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => Object.assign(acc, {[k]: v}), {})
{ b: 2, c: 0, f: 0.3, s: '', t: false }
```

Edit: this below is the version with ES5 Object.keys only: but generally with ES7 in Node v8 is pretty much enjoyable ;-)

```
> Object.keys(d)
    .filter(function(k) { return d[k] != null; })
    .reduce(function(acc, k) { acc[k] = d[k]; return acc; }, {});
{ b: 2, c: 0, f: 0.3, s: '', t: false }
```

**Update in October 2017**: with Node v8 (since v8.3 or so) now it has object spreading construct:

```
> var d = { a:undefined, b:2, c:0, d:undefined,
    e: null, f: -0.0, s: "", t: false, inf: +Infinity, nan: NaN };
undefined
> Object.entries(d)
    .filter(([ k, v ]) => (v != null))
    .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({...acc, [k]: v}), {})
{ b: 2, c: 0, f: -0, s: '', t: false, inf: Infinity, nan: NaN }
```

or within one reduce only:

```
> Object.entries(d)
   .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => (v==null ? acc : {...acc, [k]: v}), {})
{ b: 2, c: 0, f: -0, s: '', t: false, inf: Infinity, nan: NaN }
```

Update: someone want recursive? isn't that hard either, just need an additional check of isObject, and recursively call itself:

```
> function isObject(o) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === "[object Object]"; }
undefined
> function dropNullUndefined(d) {
    return Object.entries(d)
      .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => (
        v == null ? acc :
         {...acc, [k]: (isObject(v) ? dropNullUndefined(v) : v) }
      ), {});
  }
> dropNullUndefined({a: 3, b:null})
{ a: 3 }
> dropNullUndefined({a: 3, b:null, c: { d: 0, e: undefined }})
{ a: 3, c: { d: 0 } }
```

my conclusion: if pure Javascript can do, I would avoid any third party library dependencies:

Comment: You can use [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to avoid using reduce :

    Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(d).filter(([ k, v ]) => (v != null)))

Comment: I still see the parent key.  a: {b: null} , a: remains :(

Answer (score 8):

For deep nested object you can use my snippet for lodash > 4

```
const removeObjectsWithNull = (obj) => {
    return _(obj)
      .pickBy(_.isObject) // get only objects
      .mapValues(removeObjectsWithNull) // call only for values as objects
      .assign(_.omitBy(obj, _.isObject)) // save back result that is not object
      .omitBy(_.isNil) // remove null and undefined from object
      .value(); // get value
};
```

Comment: this did not remove a nested obj that had a value of null, parent key remains with no value

Comment: This initially didn't work for me because it was deleting dates and object IDs. So I replaced both instances of `isObject` with `isPlainObject` and that seemed to fix it.

Comment: this converts arrays to objects

Answer (score 7):

To remove undefined, null, and empty string from object

```
_.omitBy(object, (v) => _.isUndefined(v) || _.isNull(v) || v === '');
```

Answer (score 6):

I encountered a similar problem with removing `undefined` from an object (deeply), and found that if you are OK to convert your plain old object and use JSON, a quick and dirty helper function would look like this:

```
function stripUndefined(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description

"...If undefined, a function, or a symbol is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array)."

Comment: This is awesome :D

Answer (score 5):

Since some of you might have arrived at the question looking to specifically removing *only* `undefined`, you can use:

- a combination of Lodash methods

  ```
  _.omitBy(object, _.isUndefined)
  ```
- the [`rundef`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rundef) package, which removes only `undefined` properties

  ```
  rundef(object)
  ```

---

If you need to *recursively* remove `undefined` properties, the [`rundef`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rundef) package also has a `recursive` option.

```
rundef(object, false, true);
```

See the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rundef#usage) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Shortest way (lodash v4) to remove all the falsy values, including `null` and `undefined`:

```
_.pickBy(my_object)
```

Comment: keys with false values are removed using pickBy which uses second arg as default identity

Answer (score 3):

Here's the lodash approach I'd take:

```
_(my_object)
    .pairs()
    .reject(function(item) {
        return _.isUndefined(item[1]) ||
            _.isNull(item[1]);
    })
    .zipObject()
    .value()
```

The [pairs()](https://lodash.com/docs#pairs) function turns the input object into an array of key/value arrays. You do this so that it's easier to use [reject()](https://lodash.com/docs#reject) to eliminate `undefined` and `null` values. After, you're left with pairs that weren't rejected, and these are input for [zipObject()](https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject), which reconstructs your object for you.

Comment: Since lodash 4 there's `_.isNil` which checks for both `undefined` and `null`

Answer (score 3):

Taking in account that `undefined == null` we can write as follows:

```
let collection = {
  a: undefined,
  b: 2,
  c: 4,
  d: null,
}

console.log(_.omit(collection, it => it == null))
// -> { b: 2, c: 4 }
```

[JSBin example](https://jsbin.com/vadodirazo/edit?js,console)

Comment: revisiting this ... not sure why but this time I had to use _.omitBy ... json = _.omitBy(json, (it) => it == null);

Answer (score 3):

I like using _.pickBy, because you have full control over what you are removing:

```
var person = {"name":"bill","age":21,"sex":undefined,"height":null};

var cleanPerson = _.pickBy(person, function(value, key) {
  return !(value === undefined || value === null);
});
```

Source: https://www.codegrepper.com/?search_term=lodash+remove+undefined+values+from+object

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
const omitNullish = (object) => 
   Object.fromEntries(
       Object.entries(object).filter(([, value]) => value != null)
   )

omitNullish({ a: null, b: 1, c: undefined, d: false, e: 0 }) // { b: 1, d: false, e: 0}
```

If you want to use lodash, they are removing omit from v5 so an alternative is to use `fp/pickBy` along with `isNil` and `negate`.

```
import pickBy from 'lodash/fp/pickBy'
import isNil from 'lodash/isNil';
import negate from 'lodash/negate';


const omitNullish = pickBy(negate(isNil))

omitNullish({ a: null, b: 1, c: undefined, d: false, e: 0 }) // { b: 1, d: false, e: 0}
```

Comment: omitNullish is not a function

Comment: In which code block?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I converted your code to using "_" underscore (which must be the same thing as importing from lodash). Entered lodash.com and opened browser console to run your code and it spitted out that error. The code I was running was the following:
```let omitNullish = _.pickBy(_.negate(_.isNil));
omitNullish({ a: null, b: 1, c: undefined, d: false, e: 0 });``` 
Maybe I have missed something or misunderstood.. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thx

Comment: 'lodash/fp/pickBy' and 'lodash/pickBy' are not the same, notice the 'fp' in the import which indicates the functional programming variant of `pickBy`. So that is probably the reason why you are getting this error. 

For more information you can read more about 'lodash/fp': https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide

Comment: A working version if you want to explore: https://codesandbox.io/s/lodash-fp-forked-rrkt0?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thanks for clarification! That makes sense now :)

Answer (score 2):

[pickBy](https://lodash.com/docs/#pickBy) uses [identity](https://lodash.com/docs/#identity) by default:

```
_.pickBy({ a: null, b: 1, c: undefined, d: false });
```

Comment: I like this shorter version of @Tx3 's answer.  Works nicely!

Answer (score 2):

You can use lodash to remove null and undefined objects , but you should konw  what lodash method you need to use, many dev uses isNil to remove the Null and undefined objects , but this function not remove the empty objects (' ')

you can use isEmpty to remove Null , Undefined and

```
import pickBy from 'lodash/fp/pickBy'
import negate from 'lodash/negate';
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';

const omitNullish = pickBy(negate(isEmpty));

      addressObject = {
      "a": null,
      "c": undefined,
      "d": "",
      "e": "test1",
      "f": "test2
    }

 const notNullObjects = omitNullish(addressObject);
 
 console.log(notNullObjects);
```

> you will have this object : {
> "e": "test1",
> "f": "test2
> }

Comment: This seems to remove numbers as well, so I wouldn't recommend this if you have numbers

Answer (score 1):

**With lodash (or underscore) You may do**

```
var my_object = { a:undefined, b:2, c:4, d:undefined, e:null };

var passedKeys = _.reject(Object.keys(my_object), function(key){ return _.isUndefined(my_object[key]) || _.isNull(my_object[key]) })

newObject = {};
_.each(passedKeys, function(key){
    newObject[key] = my_object[key];
});
```

**Otherwise, with vanilla JavaScript, you can do**

```
var my_object = { a:undefined, b:2, c:4, d:undefined };
var new_object = {};

Object.keys(my_object).forEach(function(key){
    if (typeof my_object[key] != 'undefined' && my_object[key]!=null){
        new_object[key] = my_object[key];
    }
});
```

***Not to use a falsey test, because not only "undefined" or "null" will be rejected***, also is other falsey value like "false", "0", empty string, {}. Thus, just to make it simple and understandable, I opted to use explicit comparison as coded above.

Comment: this is not recursive though

Answer (score 1):

To omit all **falsey** values **but** keep the boolean primitives this solution helps.

```
_.omitBy(fields, v => (_.isBoolean(v)||_.isFinite(v)) ? false : _.isEmpty(v));
```

```js
let fields = {
str: 'CAD',
numberStr: '123',
number  : 123,
boolStrT: 'true',
boolStrF: 'false',
boolFalse : false,
boolTrue  : true,
undef: undefined,
nul: null,
emptyStr: '',
array: [1,2,3],
emptyArr: []
};

let nobj = _.omitBy(fields, v => (_.isBoolean(v)||_.isFinite(v)) ? false : _.isEmpty(v));

console.log(nobj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to remove `false` values. Here is an example:

```
obj = {
  "a": null,
  "c": undefined,
  "d": "a",
  "e": false,
  "f": true
}
_.pickBy(obj, x => x === false || x)
> {
    "d": "a",
    "e": false,
    "f": true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_object = { a:undefined, b:2, c:4, d:undefined };

var newObject = _.reject(my_collection, function(val){ return _.isUndefined(val) })

//--> newCollection = { b: 2, c: 4 }
```

Comment: _.reject treats input as array (it only accounts for the values, not keys), not a JSON. The resultant newObject is [2,4] not {b:2, c:4}. Further, It doesn't reject "null" key.

Answer (score 0):

I would use underscore and take care of empty strings too:

```js
var my_object = { a:undefined, b:2, c:4, d:undefined, k: null, p: false, s: '', z: 0 };

var result =_.omit(my_object, function(value) {
  return _.isUndefined(value) || _.isNull(value) || value === '';
});

console.log(result); //Object {b: 2, c: 4, p: false, z: 0}
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/howobajika/edit?js,console).

Answer (score 0):

**For deep nested object and arrays. and exclude empty values from string and NaN**

```
function isBlank(value) {
  return _.isEmpty(value) && !_.isNumber(value) || _.isNaN(value);
}
var removeObjectsWithNull = (obj) => {
  return _(obj).pickBy(_.isObject)
    .mapValues(removeObjectsWithNull)
    .assign(_.omitBy(obj, _.isObject))
    .assign(_.omitBy(obj, _.isArray))
    .omitBy(_.isNil).omitBy(isBlank)
    .value();
}
var obj = {
  teste: undefined,
  nullV: null,
  x: 10,
  name: 'Maria Sophia Moura',
  a: null,
  b: '',
  c: {
    a: [{
      n: 'Gleidson',
      i: 248
    }, {
      t: 'Marta'
    }],
    g: 'Teste',
    eager: {
      p: 'Palavra'
    }
  }
}
removeObjectsWithNull(obj)
```

result:

```
{
   "c": {
      "a": [
         {
            "n": "Gleidson",
            "i": 248
         },
         {
            "t": "Marta"
         }
      ],
      "g": "Teste",
      "eager": {
         "p": "Palavra"
      }
   },
   "x": 10,
   "name": "Maria Sophia Moura"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you getting here looking to remove from an array of objects and using lodash you can do something like this:

```js
 const objects = [{ a: 'string', b: false, c: 'string', d: undefined }]
 const result = objects.map(({ a, b, c, d }) => _.pickBy({ a,b,c,d }, _.identity))

 // [{ a: 'string', c: 'string' }]
```

**Note:** You don't have to destruct if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this in deep objects that include arrays with just one lodash function, `transform`.

Note that the double-unequal (!= null) is intentional as it will also match undefined, as is the typeof 'object' check as it will match both object and array.

This is for use with plain data objects only that don't contain classes.

```
const cloneDeepSanitized = (obj) =>
  Array.isArray(obj)
    ? obj.filter((entry) => entry != null).map(cloneDeepSanitized)
    : transform(
        obj,
        (result, val, key) => {
          if (val != null) {
            result[key] =
              typeof val === 'object' ? cloneDeepSanitized(val) : val;
          }
        },
        {},
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Only use and import one lodash function, also added extra omit which is empty string.

```
import omitBy from 'lodash/omitBy';

export const omitEmptyValues = (obj: object) => {
  return omitBy(obj, (value) => value === '' || value === undefined || value === null);
};
```