# Remove just undefined (not null)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am using library Lodash and I need from my javascript object remove just possible undefined properties, but I want keep null properties.

for example if I would have object like this:

```
var fooObject = {propA:undefined, propB:null, propC:'fooo'};
```

I expect output like this:

```
{propB:null, propC:'fooo'}
```

I tried this:

```
.pickBy(fooObject, _.identity);
```

but it remove also null values. Does Lodash contain some function for that? Thanks.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I want ignore just undefined, not null ...

Comment: Did you try reading **all** the answers?

Comment: `var result = _(fooObject).omitBy(_.isUndefined).value();` it's written [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31209300/1238965). And it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.omitBy` method .

For undefined and null values.

`_.isUndefined` and `_.isNull`

```
 var fooObject = {propA:undefined, propB:null, propC:'fooo'};
```

To remove `undefined` values from object

```
var newObj= _(fooObject).omitBy(_.isUndefined).value();
 console.log(newObj);
```

Incase,If you want to remove both `undefined` and `null`

```
var result = _(fooObject).omitBy(_.isUndefined).omitBy(_.isNull).value();
console.log(result);
```

Hope this helps..!

Answer (score 1):

Return anything that is NOT [_.isUndefined](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#isUndefined) :

```
_.pickBy({propA:undefined, propB:null, propC:'fooo'}, function(val){
     return !_.isUndefined(val);
});
```

Or even more nicely :

```
_.omitBy({propA:undefined, propB:null, propC:'fooo'}, _.isUndefined);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
_.pickBy(fooObject, v => v !== undefined)
```

Answer (score -1):

//simple javascript

```js
var fooObject = {propA:undefined, propB:null, propC:'fooo'};

for(var prop in fooObject)
{
if(fooObject[prop]===undefined)
delete fooObject[prop];
}
console.log(fooObject);
```