# Loopback 4 Ignore NULL properties on CRUD methods

Tags: postgresql, loopback4

I have a user model where only `user_email`(primary key/ID) is mandatory, all other properties are nullables.
I have a user service which uses a `UserRepository` for `CRUD` operations.
I'm trying to create an `UPSERT` functionality that to handle Users in my PostreSQL DB.

The code on the service is the following:

```
async upsertUser(user: User): Promise<User> {  
    try {
      await this.userRepository.replaceById(user.user_email, user);
    } catch {
      return this.userRepository.create(user);
    }
    return user;
  }
```

Note: I also tried to use the `save` method.

The problem is I don't know how can I ignore `NULL` properties.
I don't want to update all columns at once.
Let's say I just want to update session info on my database. I'm trying the following code:

```
const user: User = new User({
    user_email: this.currentUser.email,
    last_login_at: userSession.authTime,
    session_id: userSession.cookieSession,
    sys_modify_date: (new Date).toISOString()
});
await this.userService.upsertUser(user);
```

The problem of this, is that it will replace everything. If I have my `user_fullname` property set from a previous creation, it will be updated as `NULL` because the User class object has not this property filled.

How I can I ignore and not update `NULL` properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `updateById` instead of `replaceById` with lodash `pickBy` function.

firstly, remove nullish properties:

[How to remove undefined and null values from an object using lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812765/how-to-remove-undefined-and-null-values-from-an-object-using-lodash)

then:

```
this.userRepository.updateById(user.user_email, user);
```